# If no argument or not a second argument then ctx.send no argument

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im having problems with this, i want that if there is no args1 then the bot says that there is no args1, and also if there is no args2 then the bot says that there is no args2, and if there are the two args then the bot says something like: it worked perfectly! Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role(administrador)
async def playing (ctx, args1, args2):
    if not args1 in ctx.message.content:
        await ctx.send("There is not a first argument")
    elif not args2 in ctx.message.content:
        await ctx.send("There is not a second argument")
    else:
        await ctx.send("It worked perfectly!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the arguments a default value of `None` so you can see if something was passed or not.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role(administrador)
async def playing(ctx, args1=None, args2=None):
    if args1 is None:
        await ctx.send("no args1")
    elif arg2 is None:
        await ctx.send("no args2")
    else:
        await ctx.send("worked")
```